# Phoenix error in deployment: module Connection is not available

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm working on a Phoenix application and have run into a problem in production that I'm having trouble debugging.

** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Connection.start_link/2 (module Connection is not available)^M
            Connection.start_link(Postgrex.Connection, [hostname: "localhost", timeout: 5000, otp_app: :xxx, repo: xxx.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, username: "xxx", password: "xxx", database: "xxx", extensions: [{Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.DateTime, []}, {Postgrex.Extensions.JSON, [library: Poison]}], port: 5432])^M
            (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/connection.ex:27: Ecto.Adapters.Connection.connect/2^M
            (ecto) lib/ecto/pools/poolboy/worker.ex:58: Ecto.Pools.Poolboy.Worker.handle_call/3^M
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:629: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4^M
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:661: :gen_server.handle_msg/5^M
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3^M

- The application has no such trouble on my development machine
- The application is running on my production machine, but pages with database access are failing with this error
- Changes from previous hassle-free application that could be affecting this include:

  1. a more recent version of Phoenix
  2. Elixir 1.1 vs 1.0; more recent versions of Postgrex, Ecto, Exrm etc.;
  3. I'm attempting to use boldpoker/edeliver rather than a Mina recipe I had previously concocted; but I have been having a hard time edeliver has been a rocky road.

Comment: Looks like I might be running into this: https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/issues/265

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug in Postgrex which is fixed on master. Just add `:connection` to the list of applications in your `mix.exs` file.